# In Microsoft Teams, can a configurable tab send a chat message?

Tags: chatbot, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have developed a configurable Tab which works great for Microsoft Teams Meetings.  Is it possible to send a chat message from that configurable Tab app to the chat channel for that same meeting?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: I am also interested in this feature, this is possible through making a bot, specifying an endpoint which expects the channelid/chatid and sending a message in that specificatie chat/channel. But I am wondering if it is possible to do this without a bot and with a deeplink or using the Microsoft Teams Client SDK.

Comment: @JoeH You can use [connector client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.connectorclient?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) to send messages to the chat.
Use connector client in the configuration tab views controller. With getContext() in the view you will get the chatId and pass it to the controller. In the controller use the chatId as conversationId in the connector client mechanism and send the message to the chat.

Comment: @JoeH Does that help clarify?

Comment: Thanks @Mamatha-MSFT, I appreciate your response.  I'll give that a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [connector client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.connectorclient?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) to send messages to the chat. Use connector client in the configuration tab views controller. With getContext() in the view you will get the chatId and pass it to the controller. In the controller use the chatId as conversationId in the connector client mechanism and send the message to the chat.